# repeating function with time

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display sports scores every 90 seconds in an iframe. I have everything working except for one part. The issue I have is that once the time goes from 90 to 0 it loads the html page into and iframe and continues to reload the same html page forever. How can I make it load one time, and then start the 90 second countdown over again?

```
// variables
var timeCountdown = 90,
  minutesCountdown,
  secondsCountdown,
  mainCountdown;
// main script countdown
mainCountdown = setInterval(function() {
  // display countdown time
  document.getElementById("countdown").innerText = mainCountdown + " seconds remaining!";
  // if time is 0 or smaller
  if (timeCountdown <= 0) {
        // load sports scores
        document.getElementById("iframe").src = "sports/nba/feed.html";
  } else {
        // convert random time to minutes
        minutesCountdown= Math.floor(timeCountdown / 60);
        //  convert random time to seconds
        secondsCountdown = (timeCountdown % 60);
        // add leading zero to seconds if less than ten
        if (secondsCountdown < 10) {
        secondsCountdown = "0" + secondsCountdown;
        }
        // add leading zero to minutes if less than ten
        if (minutesCountdown <= 10) {
        minutesCountdown = "0" + minutesCountdown;
        }
        // display countdown until next search
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Loading NBA scores in " + minutesCountdown + ':' + secondsCountdown;
        // reduce countdown time
        timeCountdown--;
  }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>[clearInterval(intervalId)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearInterval) is what you need.</strike>

in your case it would be

```
if (timeCountdown <= 0) {
    window.clearInterval(mainCountdown);
```

Oh you want to reset the timer? Set your variable timeCountdown  back to 90!

```
if (timeCountdown <= 0) {
    timeCountdown = 90;
```

Comment: but doesn't that stop it? how will i get it to repeat over again?

Answer (score 1):

When `timeCountdown` reaches 0, and you load the iFrame, you need to set `timeCountdown` back to 90.